# Custom tab bar icon colors

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5

Im currently using Xcode 5 to develop a list oriented app.  I have a custom tint for the tab bar, custom images for the tab icons, custom tint for the tab bar's icon images when its selected, but i cannot find how to customize the icon images' tint for when its not selected.  Right now its just the default gray which you can barely see in contrast to my green tab bar.  I want to make the tab bar icons' images and names white.

Does anybody know how to set the tab bar icons' image tint in Xcode 5?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can try this to tint selected icon :

```
// Custom the tab bar
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

and this  to tint the non active icon :

```
[self.tabBarItem setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"item_seleted.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"item_unselected.png"]];
```

Comment: Note that setFinisheSelectedImage:withFinishedUnselectedImage is deprecated in iOS 7.

Comment: Matthew if its deprecated in iOS 7 is there another way to go about this or is that just because apple wants to keep the grey default icons standard?

Comment: @user2792129 - yes, just took me a few minutes to get my answer typed in <g/>

Comment: hey, what can i do if I dont want to use title..its already in the image. I want to use title space to fit icon in the center of the tabbar.

Comment: the updated way is just [[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

Answer (score 26):

You need to set the rendering mode for each tab's (unselected) image to `UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal`. So, in your app delegate, get a reference to the tab bar and then iterate over each tab bar item, adjusting the image modes.

There's probably a better way to get a reference to the tab bar, but I did the following:

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UITabBarController *tbc = [sb instantiateInitialViewController];
self.window.rootViewController = tbc;
UITabBar *tb = tbc.tabBar;
```

Then the image adjustment can be done as follows:

```
NSArray *items = tb.items;

for (UITabBarItem *tbi in items) {
    UIImage *image = tbi.image;
    tbi.selectedImage = image;
    tbi.image = [image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Matthew.  I put that code into my .m app delegate and it returned an issue that said "unsupported configuration" "Plain Style unsupported in a Navigation Item, Main.storyboard."

Comment: My code assumes that a tab bar controller is the initial view controller in the storyboard. If your app is set up differently, that may be the source of the problem.

Comment: This works but only for one of the images.  Basically I have an unselected and selected icon.  This trick made unselected work but selected is still just a blue mess.

Comment: @Halsafar That's because you are only setting the render mode for the base `image`. Do the same for the `selectedImage` although you might want to set it to a different image else you can't tell the difference between selected and not.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this purely from the storyboard without writing any code by adding a "User Defined Runtime Attribute":

1. Select your UITabViewController in the storyboard
2. Open the "Document Outline" and make sure that you select the "Tab Bar" view in the scene.
3. Show the "Identity Inspector". You should see a section for "User Defined Runtime Attributes"
4. Add the following:

   - Key Path: tintColor
   - Type: Color
   - Value: Select the color you want.

Comment: Good to know. But User Defined Runtime Attributes are an absolute debugging nightmare.

Comment: What else than tintColor can you type into Key Path?

Comment: @RasmusBidstrup, all the relevant properties of the selected IB item. In our case the UITabBar. So go to apple doc and read the UITabBar documentation.

Comment: and correct me if I am wrong but this will set the color for when you select the image. He wants to change the default grey color of the item and not the selected color?

Answer (score 5):

Try this way..it worked for me

In app delegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{


 UITabBarController *tabBarController=(UITabBarController*)(self.window.rootViewController);
    UITabBar *tabBar=tabBarController.tabBar;
  UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1=[[tabBar items] objectAtIndex:0];//first tab bar
 [tabBarItem1 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImageSelected.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImageUnselected.png"]];//image should be 30 by 30
}
```

run and go

Answer (score 5):

If you have your tab bar in visual editor, you can do it here. Select tab bar and in "User Defined Runtime Attributes" add attribute:
Key Path: selectedImageTintColor
Type: Color
Value:

Comment: Like a charm. Is there a beautiful magic for the not selected icons as well?

Answer (score 4):

Setting Custom Tabbar with selected and non-seleted Image.
Also having tabbarItem Image Insets position in center

```
UITabBar *tabBar = self.tabBarController.tabBar;

UITabBarItem *item0 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
UITabBarItem *item1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
UITabBarItem *item2 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];
UITabBarItem *item3 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:3];

[item0 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"iconBlue.png"]  withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"iconGray.png"] ];
[item1 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"iconBlue2.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-2.png"]];
[item2 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"iconBlue3.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-3.png"]];
[item3 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"iconBlue4.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-4.png"]];

item0.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 0, -6, 0);
item1.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 0, -6, 0);
item2.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 0, -6, 0);
item3.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 0, -6, 0);
```

**In viewWillAppear method of first viewcontroller. **

Answer (score 3):

Because setFinishedSelectedImage:withFinishedUnselectedImage is deprecated, I used an altered version of Ram S's answer by replacing:

```
[item0 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"iconBlue.png"]  withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"iconGray.png"] ];
```

with:

```
[item0 setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"iconGray.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
[item0 setSelectedImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"iconBlue.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
```

See [UITabBarItem setFinishedSelectedImage: deprecated in iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19563193/uitabbaritem-setfinishedselectedimage-deprecated-in-ios7) for more information.